# Discord.py Command extension doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna program a simple bot with the discord.py extension, using a tutorial to do so. Against my expectations, it doesn't work the way I want it to. The event listeners are working, but the command doesn't. Do you have any advices for me? Thanks.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Context

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="&")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot just started, thanks for reviving me.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


@client.command(
    name="ping",
    aliases=["p"]
)
async def ping_command(ctx: Context):
    print("test")
    await ctx.channel.send("Pong")


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that errors are popping up because of the ping command, and adding:

```
client.process_commands(message)
```

[under the if statement in the on_message event should fix your problem](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) (Also commented by Chuaat).